# android emulator does not show up?

Tags: android, emulation

I have an Acer Travelmate 5735Z, Ubuntu 12.04 and trying to get android SDK running.

When I run `./tools/emulator -avd MYAVD -verbose` in the SDK directory, the emulator displays no error messages (or warnings), but no GUI appears!

I have tried several things, I am desperate by now. Grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: MAke sure that MYAVD is the full path to your avd.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need install packages any more!

In directory tools, there are many types of `emulator`, while my computer works with `emulator64-arm`! My system is `Linux Mint 16 amd64`! Good luck!

```
./emulator64-arm @yxphone -sdcard yxsd -scale 0.8
```

Comment: yo I heard linux mint is taboo here. sorry pal.