# How to run WhatsApp on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, emulation

In Windows, you can run android application using BlueStack.

I was wondering, is there any way these apps can be run on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: This link will be helpful to install whats app in ubuntu. http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-use-whatsapp-mobile-application.html

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1732/can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu <br> https://askubuntu.com/questions/118903/what-android-emulators-are-available <br> https://askubuntu.com/questions/290845/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-13-04 <br> https://askubuntu.com/questions/279816/how-to-emulate-androids-applications-in-ubuntu ? And possibly the answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/248294/android-emulator-does-not-show-up

Comment: My original question was specific to WhatsApp and not other applications. Some one edited my question and now its marked as duplicate.

Comment: This isn't a reflection on the validity of your question ; it's to help people looking for a similar answer find the right resources.

Answer (score 7):

There are some android emulator available in Ubuntu but they are not as stable and usable as bluestack.

- Download the SDK

  ```
  wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r10-linux_x86.tgz
  tar -zvxf android-sdk_r10-linux_x86.tgz 
  cd android-sdk-linux_x86/
  ```
- Run android manager and install an actual sdk platform

  ```
  ./tools/android
  ```

  The go to available packages and install something like SDK Platform 2.3.3
- Now go to 'virtual devices' and create a device with the 'target' set to the SDK you installed above
- With the device highlighted, click 'start...' on the right hand side

If something doesnt work, you'll need to post exactly what you did and what the errors say

(this content is copied from the following website---)
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742803

Some more instructions can be found at

http://xmodulo.com/2013/03/how-to-run-android-emulator-on-ubuntu-or-debian.html

Comment: Please provide instructions on how to do it if you want to answer ;) It often happens that links disappear making your answer useless for future references. A copy of the link, with source is the preferred method on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind I have copied the content and added to the answer along with the link.

Comment: Then you can have an upvote from me ;-)