# How to run an Android emulator in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, emulation

Is there any way of doing this in 13.04? 
If so, can you also provide a step-by-step instruction on how to do it ?

Comment: What is the purpose? Is this for development?

Comment: no, I just want to play android app (free) like in windows (Bluestacks)

Comment: [How to emulate Androids applications in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/279816/82665) · [Can I run Android apps on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/1732/82665)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Install [VirtualBox [image: Install virtualbox]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/virtualbox) from the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Download and install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)
3. Create a new Virtual Machine with the steps [mentioned here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140718053940/http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2012/11/14/androvm-configuration-tutorial).

Comment: Looks like the download link is not working anymore.

Comment: I think this one should help: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/

Comment: Also guide link is broken

Comment: @afsharm guide link fixed! (peer review pending...)

Comment: "this file" link broken :-( could find it here http://www45.zippyshare.com/v/10597611/file.html

Comment: Can you expand this to be more explicit about what file we're looking for?

Comment: Looks like the download link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 13):

It is bit long process but I found a blog which having step by step instruction to install android emulator on ubuntu.s
Check this blog [Run Android Emulator on Ubuntu 13.04](http://surficle.com/how-to/install-whatsapp-in-ubuntu-linux/):

> ### Install Whatsapp in Ubuntu/Linux
>
> *12/29/2013, atularvind, Comment closed*
>
> Most of Android phone have “Whatsapp” application installed and
>   running. this post is for PC freak who need to install the whatsapp
>   mobile app on the ubuntu/linux. Whats app Ubuntu
>
> Here is the few easy steps for How to Install Whatsapp in the
>   ubuntu/linux. You don't need to be a programmer for installing
>   whatsapp in ubuntu. what we are going to do is installing the android
>   emulator and in it we will install whats app.
>
> 1. You need to install android emulator, for that you need to download Here is the guide that describe [how to install android emulator in the
>      ubuntu/linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101063546/http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-run-android-emulator-on-ubuntu.html)
> 2. After installing & running the android emulator you need to open a browser in it.
>
> Whats app android+ ubuntu
>
> 3. In the browser open Google and search for *“what app for android“*. or go to the link http://www.whatsapp.com/android/ for downloading
>      whatsapp apk file. click on Download now.
> 4. After Downloading the file install the whatsapp Apk file under your emulator. 
>     [image: Whats app ubuntu]
> 5. Whatsapp will ask for mobile varification. choose your country and enter your mobile number, in order to verify the mobile SIM card. 
>     [image: Whatsapp ubuntu]
> 6. After the SIM varification whatsapp will ask for the personal information like photo, name. and click next in order to complete the
>      whatsapp installation. 
>     [image: install whats app linix]
>
> After following This steps you can use the whats app under the any
>   version of Ubuntu.

*Copy of https://web.archive.org/web/20130805194456/http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-run-android-emulator-on-ubuntu.html from the above article*:

> *Monday, May 13, 2013*
>
> ### How to install/run Android emulator on Ubuntu or Debian
>
> Here is guide on how to run Android emulator on Ubuntu or Debian.
>   Android emulator comes with Android SDK, and therefore you need to
>   install Android SDK. Follow the steps below to install Android SDK on
>   Linux.
>
> [image]
>
> Android SDK requires Java JDK. Therefore install Java JDK first.
>
> To install Java JDK on Ubuntu or Debian:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
> ```
>
> To install Java JDK on CentOS, Fedora or RHEL, first set up Repoforge
>   repository on your system, and then run the following.
>
> ```
> sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
> ```
>
> Now download Android SDK ADT bundle from Android official site. Unzip
>   the downloaded ADT bundle, and copy the sdk directory to your
>   preferred location. Here I assume that the installation directory of
>   Android SDK is ~/android-sdks.
>
> For 64-bit Linux user: you must install another prerequisite called
>   ia32-libs since Android emulator is 32-bit software. The ia32-libs
>   package contains a set of runtime libraries for the ia32/i386
>   architecture, configured for use on a 64-bit kernel. On 64-bit Linux,
>   the mksdcard utility which creates SD cards will fail without this
>   package.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
> ```
>
> While using ia32-libs, if you encounter any error with 32-bit
>   libGL.so, do the following:
>
> ```
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0 /usr/lib/libGL.so
> ```
>
> In order to run Android emulator, you first need to create a new AVD
>   (Android Virtual Device) which is an emulator configuration for the
>   Android device to be emulated. To create a new AVD, first launch
>   Android SDK Manager by running the following.
>
> ```
>  ~/android-sdks/tools/android
> ```
>
> Go to “Tools” > “Manage AVDs” on Android SDK Manager’s menu. It will
>   open up AVD Manager.
>
> Click on “Add” button to create a new AVD. An example configuration of
>   a new AVD is shown below.
>
> [image]
>
> If an AVD has been successfully created, you will see the following
>   confirmation.
>
> [image]
>
> You can check the list of available AVDs as follows.
>
> ```
> ~/android-sdk/android list avds   
>
>  Available Android Virtual Devices:  
>    Name: my_avd  
>    Path: /home/xmodulo/.android/avd/my_avd.avd  
>   Target: Android 4.2 (API level 17)  
>     ABI: armeabi-v7a  
>    Skin: 800x1280  
>   Sdcard: 1G
> ```
>
> To launch Android emulator with the AVD that you have created,
>   highlight the AVD on AVD Manager, and click on “Start” button on the
>   right sidebar.
>
> [image]
>
> Alternatively, you can start Android emulator directly from command
>   line as follows. In this case, specify “`@[your_avd_name]`” as an
>   argument to the emulator.
>
> ```
>  emulator @my_avd
> ```
>
> Booting up Android emulator may be slow (even taking minutes)
>   depending on your hardware. Once Android emulator is successfully
>   launched, you will see an running instance of Android device.
>
> [image]
>
> Have a Happy Droiding!

**Edit:** [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) is again a good option, this is the guide to  [Install GenyMotion in ubuntu 13.04](http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/10/install-genymotion-in-linuxubuntu-1304.html)

**Another Edit (by someone else :) :** Since the above genymotion link is dead and it is very good, [here is a guide for 14.04](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-genymotion-in-ubuntu-14-04/):

> ### Install Genymotion
>
> - First install virtualbox
>
>   ```
>   sudo apt-get install virtualbox
>   ```
> - Click below to register on Genymotion site, and download either 32bit or 64bit version depending on your hardware architecture *(to find what you are using, you can read [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/41332/178596))*
>
> [Genymotion Registration Page](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/customer/login/)
>
> - Change directory to where you downloaded the bin file and run following commands. Accept the default install path
>
>   ```
>   chmod +x genymotion-2.2.2_x64.bin
>
>   ./genymotion-2.2.2_x64.bin
>   ```
> - Change directory to where genymotion was installed. The default is `/home/[username]/genymotion/`
>
>   ```
>   cd /home/[username]/genymotion/
>
>   ./genymotion
>   ```
> - Click Yes to add your first virtual device [image]
> - Click Connect to login and install a device [image]
> - Select desired device and click Next [image]
> - Enter a name for your device and click Next [image]
> - Wait until your virtual device is downloaded and deployed [image]
> - Click Finish [image]
> - Click Play to start the emulator [image]

Comment: You can also apparently install Google services... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20137324/2943276).

Comment: The first link in this answer (run android emulator...) and third link (install genymotion...) lead to dead links (apparently removed by blogspot).

Comment: The first link can be found in wayback machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140101063546/http://surficle.com/how-to/install-whatsapp-in-ubuntu-linux/), haven't found a copy of the second yet...

Comment: I have made a load of edits so this should be useful, even when the rest of the links die :)

Comment: Just copying from others...

Answer (score 2):

Install an app called [Genymotion](https://cloud.genymotion.com/) and the rest will just flow...the best android emulator available on Ubutu

Answer (score 1):

- Install VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software Center
- Follow this guide to install the Android Emulator:
  http://blog.laptopmag.com/create-android-emulator

The guide is for VirtualBox, so not OS specific and should work for all versions of
Ubuntu. It will take you about 10 minutes to install.

Download the boot-disk from http://www.android-x86.org

- Android 4.2: Android-x86-4.2-devel
- Android 4.3: Android-x86-4.3-devel

Answer (score -6):

Download the SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and install ia32-libs (if you are using 64 bit system)

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```