# Trying to put kik on my Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wine

I would like to use kik on my laptop. 
I am new to programming.
Hp probook 4430's 64 processor
I have wine but dont know how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run an Android emulator in Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290845/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 2):

Just Install a android emulator and then you can run any android app into this.
Genymotion is one nice emulator you can download it from this link, http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/10/install-genymotion-in-linuxubuntu-1304.html
Or you can use this, http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-run-android-emulator-on-ubuntu.html

I am currently using kik,whatsapp,instagram under genymotion.

Hope it works with ur case too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well i included all the requirements needed so as to satisfy the solution for the above problem and I did include references. Could you please tell me , what I am missing here.

Comment: Welll both links are now dead, so aren't much use to anyone - similar answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/314313/178596) which has one of those links.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about KiK Messenger? It's not supported right now. It's supported for Windows, IOS , and Android, Blackberry and OVI. 
for more info :

[kik](http://kik.com/)

Comment: Well Isn't wine supposed to run Windows?