# Android emulator

Tags: virtualbox, games, android

I installed virtualbox, but now what? 
I'm computer illiterate.

There's just one specific game I'm trying to play. My smartphone was stolen in a home invasion and this is really the least of my problems, yet here I am. I downloaded the game, I downloaded virtualbox. The game says there is no device installed.

Opened virtualbox and got as far as this message:

On the System page, you have assigned more than 50% of your computer's memory (1001.00 MB) to the virtual machine. There might not be enough memory left for your host operating system. Continue at your own risk.

Comment: It seems you are missing the point of virtual machines: you need to download a copy of the Android operating system, install that in a virtual machine, and then try to install the game in the virtual machine. From your question, I can't tell whether you have installed Android. If all you want to do is play the game, you can ignore the memory warning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an Android emulator in Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/290845/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the actual fixes for the error:

```
On the System page, you have assigned more than 50% of your computer's memory (1001.00 MB) to the virtual machine. There might not be enough memory left for your host operating system. Continue at your own risk
```

could be:

- Assign less RAM to the Virtual Machine - I think Android is happy to run with a minimum of 128 MB of memory available, but a game will likely require more.
- Ignore the error and continue - you will likely need to close every over program before running Android otherwise you computer may drastically slow down/crash
- Use a computer with more memory if available, or upgrade the amount of RAM in your computer

---

Install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then you can use [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) to install Android for you.

[Find out whether your computer is 32bit or 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/q/41332/178596), then download the right [32bit](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.1.1/genymotion-2.1.1_x86.bin) or [64bit](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.1.1/genymotion-2.1.1_x64.bin) version.

Then you can use [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20131017232734/http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/10/install-genymotion-in-linuxubuntu-1304.html) to install it - basically, make the downloaded `.bin` file executable, then run it in terminal inside the folder you want it to install to - I think the terminal has to be in the same folder as well.

Then you can download the Android VM and run it inside Genymotion - you can open Genymotion by clicking on the `genymotion` executable.