# Android apps in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-sdk

I use Ubuntu on a netbook and am looking for a way to run reasonably basic android apps. The only ways to do that I've seen are to either run the emulator from the SDK or a VM, but those aren't really great options for people like me on underpowered computers.

What I was wondering is if anyone here knew of an alternative to this setup. All I really need is something capable of interpreting android apps in desktop linux and spoofing any information like location or accelerometer data (so no playing games or even 3D work). It could be in development (just so long as I can follow along), I'm just hoping it exists.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224472/bluestacks-emulator-for-linux

Comment: You may also wish to look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/290845/178596) - emulators like GenyMotion I think are made with app development in mind.