# How can I download wattpad on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation

The command `sudo apt-get install wattpad` is not working. I want to download wattpad on my Ubuntu 16.04, but when I enter that command on terminal, I get

```
E: Unable to locate package wattpad
```

Comment: What makes you think `wattpad` is available for Linux?

Comment: does wattpad is not available for ubuntu?

Comment: The command for deciding a package name is : `apt-cache search [name]` ... or part of "name" →  `apt-cache search wattpad`

Comment: That's not very helpful though is it? I mean, OP still doesn't know whether and how they can install the app after reading that if the package isn't in any APT repository in some form...

Comment: @Zanna Answer provided.

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment `wattpad` is not available for Ubuntu (nor any other desktop OS). To the best of my knowledge it's a mobile app only available for [IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wattpad/id306310789?mt=8) or [android.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wp.wattpad&hl=en) An alternative might be to run an [Android VM.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290845/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-in-ubuntu-13-04/290880) and install it on the VM via Google Play using the android link above.