# How can I run the Android Revolut finance app with Ubuntu?

Tags: android-emulator

I would like to run the Android Revolut finance app with my Ubuntu laptop (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS). Would you tell me how to achieve this?

(Here is a link to the app in order to avoid misunderstandings:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.revolut.revolut)

Unfortunately the app cannot be installed on my smart phone. The appstore says my phone is incompatible. So I would appreciate a way to run the app on my laptop instead.

Thankyou very much and wish you a wonderful day <(^_^)>

Comment: Have you tried any solutions yet? Some recent, similar questions have been closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1732/can-i-run-android-apps-on-ubuntu) although, some of the answers are outdated. Arc welder is no longer available, but there are [other solutions like genymotion](https://askubuntu.com/a/290880) appear to be supported. Also, running in a virtual box or similar machine, you can run [Android x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) which runs from an ISO file like the Ubuntu installer but not all apps support AMD/Intel based or x86 like processors.

Comment: Also, what version of Ubuntu and which desktop setup are you using? Waydroid is supposed to work on a Wayland based desktop although personally, I tried it out and it didn't work for me and I didn't bother to try and get it working. Running Wayland instead of x11 seems to be a requirement, though.

Comment: There's also [Android Studio from Google](https://developer.android.com/studio), which used as a testing and development environment although it can be kind of resource heavy.

Comment: I installed waydroid. The first impression is fine. My laptop has a touch screen and waydroid feels like a tablet OS with the screen ^^ I haven´t figured out how to install any apps from the appstore though. Also Revolut probably has some external dependencies. But I don´t know how to look them up and even if I did, I do not know how to install them using an emulated non-google Android OS.

Comment: waydroid also ships without an appstore. So that would be needed as well in order to install Revolut and get updates...

Comment: This is a finance app, so security should be considered. The apk must be retrieved reliably via a trusted source like google playstore or similar.

Comment: [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/revolut-ltd/revolut-better-than-your-bank/) is generally trusted as it's manually vetted by Android Police. Also, custom ROMs/emulators cannot bundle Play Store by default due to licensing. You have to manually flash Play Store frameworks, e.g. [Open GApps](https://opengapps.org/).

Comment: (at)AndrewT. thankyou, I will try APK Mirror

(at)mchid I am using standard Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Bliss OS might be a good solution. It recommends a stand alone installation of the OS though... I'd like to my existing Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Download the apk for the google play store to install the app from google play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or [waydroid](https://waydro.id/) to install android apps on Linux.

[genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is an android phone emulator, and [waydroid](https://waydro.id/) is more a sort of container that allow you to install an android app like it was an Linux application.

To install the **Revolut finance** app you will surely need google playstore. By default genymotions doesn't have google apps installed, you can achieve this by following theses [instructions](https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/4414586104977-How-to-install-Google-Play-Store-and-other-Google-Apps-in-Genymotion). For waydroid you have to select gapps on **Android Type** select at the first launch.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. What Arthur is recommending is to edit your answer and simply include the basic steps from the article. Since you already referenced the article, including the steps wouldn't be like copying it as an answer. This prevents link only answers on Askubuntu and also helps us avoid the pitfalls of linkrot. Thanks.